# Container's height doesn't be exact as on my screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angular

I have just started web developing a few months ago and I designed my websites. You can look: [WEBSITE](https://www.shellvoide.com)

Height of containers on my screen are not same on other computer screens. I know it's due to screen height. But i want my website the look exact as it looks on my screen on other screens. So my question is how to do that. Here a screenshot from my screen: 
[image: Screenshot]

I noted that when i open my website on some of my friends laptops and computers, the height of containers are different but actually there are not different. Its screen resolution. So, finding a solution for this.

Comment: Share some css and html etc.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to understand why your question isn't suitable.

Comment: in your CSS, try `position: absolute;`, and `min-width: `*resolution*`;` for the best results. Hope this helped!

Comment: You should also specify what do you mean by "look the same". Does it means the same in terms of screen percentage or screen alignment or pixel size.... ?

Comment: *"But i want my website the look exact as it looks on my screen on other screens."* That's not always an achievable or desirable result. You will spend your life chasing your tail. Instead think about [responsive web design](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the code of your site and the containers you have 250px height and 33% width. Your images are set to have 100% width and height and overflow is set to hidden. This means that your images will be stretch and shrink depending on the screen resolution. What you want to have is width: 100% and height: auto on images. And your containers around images shouldn't have overflow: hidden and height: 250px.